# Scss/Sass not working with sinatra-assetpack

Tags: sinatra, sass, sinatra-assetpack

I'm writing a [classic style sinatra app](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html), and trying to package my scss files with [sinatra-assetpack](http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/), but it's not working.

This is my main web file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'sass'
require 'compass'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'

set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
set :environment, ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"

configure do
  Compass.configuration do |config|
    config.project_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
    config.sass_dir = 'views/stylesheets'
  end

  set :haml, { :format => :html5 }
  set :scss, Compass.sass_engine_options

  assets {
    serve '/javascripts', from: 'public/javascripts'
    serve '/stylesheets', from: '/stylesheets'

    # The second parameter defines where the compressed version will be served.
    # (Note: that parameter is optional, AssetPack will figure it out.)
    js :lib, '/javascripts/script.js', [
      '/javascripts/lib/modernizr-2.5.3.js',
      '/javascripts/lib/underscore-min.js',
      '/javascripts/lib/slides.min.jquery.js',
      '/javascripts/lib/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js'
    ]

    css :app, '/stylesheets/screen.css', [
      '/stylesheets/screen.css',
      '/fonts/meta.css'
    ]

    js_compression  :jsmin
    css_compression :sass
  }
end
```

I'm using this in my layout file:

```
= css :app, :media => 'screen'
```

The `screen.scss` file is stored in `/views/stylesheets/screen.scss`, and the `meta.css` is in `/public/fonts/meta.css`. Are the references to `screen.css` incorrect? Should they be served from a different directory?

Also I had this in my main web file

```
get '/stylesheets/screen.css' do
  content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
  scss :'stylesheets/screen'
end
```

Putting it in or removing it didn't fix anything - is this route necessary?

Comment: It seems to place assets block in root scope, but I've not tried it out yet...
Please see the following. There is sample code in example directory.
https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack

Answer (score 0):

You should not keep your `get '/stylesheets/screen.css'` route anymore.

I also noticed you have compass in your Gemfile / app files. Sinatra AssetPack notes that it is not compatible with compass. You can include `sinatra/support` though to use it such as their example application [here](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack/tree/master/examples/compass).

Change your `serve '/stylesheets', from: '/stylesheets'` statement to `serve '/stylesheets', from: '/views/stylesheets'` to reflect where you would like to serve the sass files from.

After all that, you should be able to serve your javascript and scss like below:

```
= css :app, :media => 'screen'
= js :lib
```